# Does Nextjs generate duplicate pages at build time?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

So I haven't found this answer anywhere and I would like to know this so that's why posting here. Suppose I have a blog for which I want to use SSG and ISR. SSG for the homepage and ISR for the individual posts.

So if I generated the homepage at build time with SSG to display 10 posts with the following code:

index.js file:

```
export const getStaticProps = async () => {

    const posts = await get10PostsFromDB();

    return {
        props: {
            posts
        }
    }

}
```

And then, if I use this code for each post and also use getStaticPaths to generate those exact 10 posts:

[post].js

```
export const getStaticPaths = async () => {

    const posts = await get10PostsFromDB();

    const paths = posts.map( ( item ) => ( {
        params: {
            slug: item.slug
        }
    } ) );

    return {
        paths,
        fallback: 'blocking'
    };

}


export const getStaticProps = async ({ params }) => {

    const post = await getASinglePostFromDB( params.slug );

    return {
        props: { 
            post 
        },
        revalidate: 1,
        notFound: true
    }

}
```

Will there be duplicate SSG generated pages as 10 are generated at build time for the homepage and then again those 10 pages are generated for `getStaticPaths` as well? Or what I'm thinking is totally wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have a bit of a misunderstanding of what `getStaticPaths` and `getStaticProps` do.

Short answer: no, it will not duplicate the pages.

Let me explain why:

## `getStaticProps` vs `getStaticPaths`

- `getStaticProps` (Static Generation): **Fetch data at build time.**
- `getStaticPaths` (Static Generation): **Specify dynamic routes to pre-render pages based on data.**

### What does `getStaticProps` do?

NextJS has this built-in page pre-rendering but this built-in process has a flaw if you wanna call it like this.

Take this code for example:

```
    const HomePage = () => {
    const [loadedPosts, setLoadedPosts] = useState();

    useEffect(() => {
        setLoadedPosts(DUMMY_POSTS);
    }, []);

    return (
        loadedPosts ? (
            <PostList posts={loadedPosts} />
        ) : ''
    )
}
```

**Note:** This is a simple demo to convey the concept. In normal cases this issue will occur when you fetch data from an API in the `useEffect` hook.

**Explanation:** Let's imagine we are rendering a list of posts. `DUMMY_POSTS` is our data that comes from the db for example.

What happens here is that the `useEffect` hook will wait for the component to render before updating out `loadedPosts`.

When NextJS pre-renders a page it takes the **snapshot of the first component rendering cycle** as its content and that might be missing crucial data. This means that **NextJS does not update the snapshot of our code AFTER the new data has come.** This as you know is bad for SEO.

After this HTML page was received on the client, React will actually take over, the page is *hydrated* as this process is called, which means that now React will turn this into a single page application, take over control, and then this `useEffect` function will be executed, data might be fetched and the page might be updated - not on the server, not on the pre-rendered page but instead after this page was received in the browser. I.e no SSR.

Here's where `getStaticProps()` comes to play.

```
const HomePage = (props) => {
    return (
      <PostList posts={props.posts} />
    )
}

export function getStaticProps() {
    // fetch data from an API
    return {
        props: {
            posts: DUMMY_POSTS
        },
        revalidate: 10
    };
};

export default HomePage;
```

`getStaticProps` runs at build time and it fetches the data `DUMMY_POSTS` and then assigns it to `props`. This is then passed as props of the HomePage component where we can access `props.posts`.

### What is `getStaticPaths`?

`getStaticPaths` is a function that you **need** to export in a page component file that is:

1. A **dynamic** page and
2. Is using **`getStaticProps`**

You **DO NOT** need it in a file that is using `getServerProps` and **DO NOT NEED IT WITHOUT** `getStaticProps`

Here I will use a very simple example to explain, but normally you generate the paths dynamically as you have done in your example:

```
export async function getStaticPaths() {
    return {
      fallback: false,
        paths: [
            { 
              params: {
                postdId: 'p1'
              }
            },
            { 
              params: {
                postId: 'p2'
              }
            },
        ]
    };
};
```

In the above example, we have two posts with IDs p1 and p2.

With `getStaticProps` a page is generated during the build process. This means that Next.js needs to pre-generate all versions for all dynamic pages in advance for all supported dynamic paths. Since it's dynamic Next.js needs to know for which IDs it needs to pre-generate a page. These functions are run **during the build process** **NOT** when a client visits the page. I.e. without `getStaticPaths` these dynamic pages will not be pre-generated on the server which kills the purpose of Next.js.

`getStaticPaths` tells Next.js what are the exact dynamic paths (in our case which post IDs) it needs to pre-generate. If the user enters an ID for which we did not pre-generate a page they will see a 404 error.

`getStaticPaths` returns an object where we describe all of the dynamic segment values. It has a `paths` property, which is an **array** that **takes an object** for each version of the dynamic page. This object has a `params` property, which is also an **object** that **holds all of the key-value pairs** that lead to your dynamic page.

## TLDR;

`getStaticProps` fetches the data at build time before the component has loaded so that Next.js can pre-render the page WITH the data that we are fetching.

`getStaticPaths` tells Next.js about dynamic pages that need to be pre-rendered, because Next.js will not pre-render them on its own as it does not know exactly the dynamic IDs (routes). With this function you are basically telling Next.js how your dynamic routes are called so it knows what to pre-render. Otherwise it will show a 404 page.

Conclussion:
NextJS does not generate duplicate pages at build time.

## EDIT:

In regards to pre-generating pages with `getStaticPaths`...

You DO NOT need to pre-generate every single dynamic route. In order to be able to load the other routes without a 404 error, you can add `fallback: true` or `fallback: 'blocking'`

These options can help in cases where you have a lot of pages that need to be pre-generated. In the case we have a website like Amazon with millions of products, pre-rendering all of them might take super long and there may be products that are rarely visited. Therefore, pre-generating such products is a waste of resources.

In such cases, we can set `fallback: true` and pre-generate some pages, not all.

```
export async function getStaticPaths() {
return {
    fallback: true,
    paths: [
        {
            params: {
                prodId: 'p1'
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

}

Even if we don't list all of the pages, this setting tells NextJS that other pages can be valid and should be loaded **when they are visited**. They are **generated just in time**. This allows to pre-generate highly visited pages and pre-generate other pages only when they are needed.

However, if the request with the unsupported ID is sent directly (not internally through clicking on a product), it will return a 404. In such cases, we need to have a fallback case in our component.

```
const ProductDetailPage = ({ loadedProducts }) => {
if (!loadedProducts) {
    return <p>Loading...</p>
}

return (
    <>
        <h1>{loadedProducts.title}</h1>
        <p>{loadedProducts.description}</p>)
    </>
)
```

}

In the above code, the user will see the Loading indicator instead of a 404 page, until the data comes and is then displayed on the page.

An alternative would be to set `fallback: 'blocking'`. In those cases, we don't need a fallback in the component, but the response will take a little longer.

```
const ProductDetailPage = ({ loadedProducts }) => {

    return (
        <>
            <h1>{loadedProducts.title}</h1>
            <p>{loadedProducts.description}</p>)
        </>
    )
}

export async function getStaticPaths() {
    return {
        fallback: 'blocking,
        paths: [
            {
                params: {
                    prodId: 'p1'
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

It depends on your case. Sometimes you need to show something quickly (`fallback: true`). Sometimes it's worth waiting for it and you don't want to show an incomplete page to your visitors (`fallback: 'blocking'`).

[Read more about NextJS's Data fetching](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching) here.

Comment: Mate, thanks a lot for such a detailed answer. Learnt and understood so many new things. However, let me summarize and ask you a question to understand it better. So suppose I have 1000 posts. Do I have to call getStaticPaths in the dynamic route for all of 1000 posts or one would do?

Comment: You have to map through your data (let's say it's DUMMY_POSTS, you will need their IDs) in getStaticPaths for all dynamic paths that you have so that Next.js knows in advance what to pre-render. So in this case, yes you have to map through all 1000 posts, but that's done once in the dynamic route file.

Comment: @Zak I've edited the answer with an explanation of other alternatives when using `getStaticPaths` for cases where you do not want to pre-generate everything.