# Redux toolkit store reset automatically in navigating between pages in next js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, next.js, redux-toolkit

I'm a new Next user and have been using Redux with React for a long time
I had a lot of trouble in using  Redux with Next

I'm done with this solution

**store.js**

```
import { configureStore } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import reducers from './rootReducer';

export function makeStore() {
  return configureStore({
    reducer: reducers,
  });
}

const store = makeStore();

export default store;
```

**rootReducer.js**

```
import { combineReducers } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import tes from './test/tes';

const reducers = combineReducers({
  test: tes,
});

export default reducers;
```

**_app.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import store from '../redux/store';
import { createWrapper } from 'next-redux-wrapper';

const MyApp = ({ Component, ...rest }) => {
  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <Component {...rest} />
    </Provider>
  );
};
const makestore = () => store;
const wrapper = createWrapper(makestore);

export default wrapper.withRedux(MyApp);
```

But I discovered that any use of the useDispatch
Inside any page, the search engine does not recognize the content of the page after fetching the data

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import { Test } from '../../redux/test/tes';
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import Link from 'next/link';

function TestPage() {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const { data } = useSelector((state) => state.test);
  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(Test('hi'));
  }, []);
  return (
    <div>
      <Link href="/">
        <a>home</a>
      </Link>{' '}
      {data.map((name) => (
        <h1>{name.title}</h1>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}

export default TestPage;
```

One of the next pre-render methods must be used

**I wonder if this is normal with next**

**or there Is a better way for doing that?**

---

**#1 Update**

Now after moving data fetching to `getStaticProps`

**TestPage.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import { Test } from '../../redux/test/tes';
import {  useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import Link from 'next/link';
import { wrapper } from '../../redux/store';

function TestPage({ pageProps }) {
  const { data } = useSelector((state) => state.test);
  console.log(data);

  return (
    <div>
      <Link href="/">
        <a>home</a>
      </Link>{' '}
      {data && data.map((name) => (
        <h1>{name.name}</h1>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
export const getStaticProps = wrapper.getStaticProps(
  (store) => async (context) => {
    const loading = store.getState().test.loading;
    if (loading === 'idle') {
      await store.dispatch(Test('hi'));

    }

    return {
      props: {  },
    };
  }
);

export default TestPage;
```

The problem now is that the store is not updating
`useSelector return []`

Although `console.log (data)` from getStaticProps the data is present
`__NEXT_REDUX_WRAPPER_HYDRATE__`
i'm stuck

---

**#2 Update**

It was really hard to get here and after that, there are still problems getting Redux with Next js

Now everything works until navigating to any page have  `getStaticProps` or `getServerProps`

state getting reset automatically

**store.js**

```
import reducers from './rootReducer';
import { configureStore } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import { createWrapper, HYDRATE } from 'next-redux-wrapper';

const reducer = (state, action) => {
  if (action.type === HYDRATE) {
    let nextState = {
      ...state,
      ...action.payload,
    };
    return nextState;
  } else {
    return reducers(state, action);
  }
};

const isDev = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development';

const makeStore = (context) => {
  let middleware = [];

  const store = configureStore({
    reducer,
    middleware: (getDefaultMiddleware) =>
      getDefaultMiddleware().concat(middleware),
    devTools: isDev,
    preloadedState: undefined,
  });

  return store;
};

export const wrapper = createWrapper(makeStore, { debug: isDev });
```

Comment: Not sure if it's related, but your code above both imports and defines the function `Test` in the same file. Surely you didn't mean to do that.

Comment: actually, I changed the name of the import manual here because its name was strange But everything is fine with me from this side, thank you. But can you tell me if my question is clear or not so that I can get an answer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the end, this way only worked. Even the server and Client state separation did not work.

I used this [jsondiffpatch](http://%20https://github.com/benjamine/jsondiffpatch).

**rootReducer.js**

```
const rootReducer = createReducer(
  combinedReducers(undefined, { type: '' }),
  (builder) => {
    builder
      .addCase(HYDRATE, (state, action) => {
        const stateDiff = diff(state, action.payload);
        const isdiff = stateDiff?.test?.data?.[0];
        const isdiff1 =
          stateDiff?.test1?.data?.[0] 
        return {
          ...state,
          ...action.payload,

          test: isdiff ? action.payload.test : state.test,
          test1: isdiff1 ? action.payload.test1 : state.test1,
        };
      })
      .addDefaultCase(combinedReducers);
  }
);
```

The only problem here is that you have to test every change in every piece inside the state

### Update

Because a global hydrate reducer can be overkill, here is an example to handle hydration in each slice:

```
import { createSlice, createAsyncThunk } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import { diff } from 'jsondiffpatch';
import { HYDRATE } from 'next-redux-wrapper';

const initialState = {
  data: [],
};
export const TestFetch = createAsyncThunk(
  'TestFetch',
  async (data, { rejectWithValue, dispatch }) => {
    try {
      const response = await fetch(
        'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users'
      );
      const d = await response.json();
      return d;
    } catch (error) {
      return rejectWithValue(error.response.data.error);
    }
  }
);

const test = createSlice({
  name: 'test',
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    update: {
      reducer: (state, { payload }) => {
        return { ...state, data: payload };
      },
    },
  },
  extraReducers: {
    [HYDRATE]: (state, action) => {
      const stateDiff = diff(state, action.payload);
      const isdiff1 = stateDiff?.server?.[0]?.test?.data?.[0];
      // return {
      //   ...state,
      //   data: isdiff1 ? action.payload.server.test.data : state.data,
      // };
      state.data = isdiff1 ? action.payload.server.test.data : state.data;
    },
    [TestFetch.fulfilled]: (state, action) => {
      state.data = action.payload;
    },
  },
});

export const { update } = test.actions;
export default test.reducer;
```

Comment: Good to know that you found an answer by yourself. Did you confirm that page content is properly pre-rendered?

Comment: Yes, I am sure of this, but I did not know whether this method is correct or it is overkill All examples work without diff

Comment: It's written in the document that you should implement your own hydration logic. I don't have enough experience with hydrating. That's why I think you've done a good work.

Comment: Hydration logic is too complicated, so I use context hook api instead of redux if the props is used for pre-rendering

Comment: I was about to switch over to the Context API but it looked like a challenge
I saw that there are examples that work and they use the first method, so it was necessary to know what is happening. I would really like to thank you. I did not expect that you will see the question

Answer (score 3):

> 1.) **Does using Redux with Nextjs eliminate the SEO advantage?**

No, using Redux with NextJs does not hinder the SEO advantage. Redux goes well with NextJS.

The problem lies with your implementation of the data fetching. NextJS does not see the fetched content, because you need to fetch it in either `getInitialProps`, `getServerSideProps`, or `getStaticProps` depending on the way you want your app to work.

See the [Data Fetching documentation](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/data-fetching/get-initial-props) from NextJS.

Note that `getServerSideProps` and `getStaticProps` are the recommended ways of dealing with data fetching.

If you go for `getStaticProps`, you will need `getStaticPaths`. Check this answer to see use cases and the [difference between the `getStaticPaths` and `getStaticProps`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70040035/11735399) as it can be confusing.

TLDR; Instead of putting the data fetching in a useEffect hook, move it inside a `getServerSideProps` or a `getStaticProps` function.

Comment: Does this mean that I should use store obj instead of redux hooks inisde next pre render methods ?

Comment: Can you see the update please?